# Use :order with find_by_id

Tags: ruby-on-rails-2

In my Rails application I have a `Device` and a `DevicePort` class with a one to many relationship between them.

In my `device` controller I get a list of all the ports belonging to that device but I can't seem to order them:

```
@device_ports = Device.find_by_id(params[:id], :order => 'id ASC').device_ports
```

This doesn't seem to work and doesn't give any syntax errors either.

In the view I am simply doing:

```
<% @device_ports.each do |device_port| %>
    ...
<% end %>
```

Is anyone able to explain why the ports aren't being sorted by id?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to order `device_ports`, I'd do something like this:

```
@device_ports = Device.find(params[:id]).device_ports.all(:order => 'id ASC')
```

Comment: Why you use `find_by_id!` and not just `find`?

Comment: @toro2k thanks. I had my mind fixed on this `find_by_id`, like in the question.

Answer (score 1):

```
@device_ports = Device.exists?(params[:id]) ? Device.find_by_id(params[:id]).device_ports : []
```

if you want order on device sports do following

```
@device_ports = Device.exists?(params[:id]) ? Device.find_by_id(params[:id]).device_ports.order('id ASC') : []
```

For rails 2.x.x use following

```
@device_ports = DeviceSport.find(:all, :conditions => ["device_id = ?", params[:id]], :order => 'id ASC' )
```

Comment: thanks, I get the following error though: `undefined method 'order' for #<Class:0x102816d90>`

Comment: @martincarlin87 what version of Rails do you use?

Comment: @MarekLipka it's 2.3.14, sorry, I should probably have mentioned that in the question.

Comment: @martincarlin87 Indeed, you should have, that's why Salil's answer doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you are ordering just the devices, the ports are randomly being fetched. You can eager load your association and order the ports with this:

```
Device.includes(:device_ports).where('devices.id = ?', params[:id]).order('device_ports.id')
```

Make note about the query that is generated. You have access to the ports table when you join  them.

UPDATE:

If you want the other way around:

```
DevicePort.includes(:device).where('devices.id = ?', params[:id]).order('device_ports.id')
```

Only the association inside the `includes` is changed.

Comment: thanks, I am getting the following error though : `private method 'include' called for #<Class:0x10268cc40>`

Comment: Ops, sorry, my bad. Use `includes`

Comment: thanks, changed it but error is just the same :P `undefined method 'includes'`. The Rails version is 2.3.14 if that makes a difference?

Comment: Oh, it makes all the difference. =/ The syntax is different.

Comment: Check right here:  http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v2.3.8/active_record_querying.html#joining-tables

Comment: @martincarlin87 check out my answer. I think I know the solution.